# Returning a Dataframe instead of a string from a class

Tags: pandas, dataframe, finance

Hi I'm new to writing classes and am having some difficulty with getting my intended results out in an easy to read/process manner.

Ideally I'd be able to return a dataframe with a function instead of returning a fairly messy string via  `__str__` method to improve my index-ability (if that's a word!).

Currently I'm using something of the form:

```
 def __str__(self):
    str = """ Semi-Standard Deviation: {}\n Annualised Semi Standard Deviation: {}\n\n \n\n maximum annual return: {}
    \n minimum annual return: {} 
    """.format(self.semistddv()[0],self.semistddv()[1],self.yearly_returns()[1],self.yearly_returns()[2],self.yearly_returns()[3],
               )
    return(str)
```

But I'd love to be able to format it more like:

```
 data = np.array([['Figure','Value'],
            ['Semi-Standard-Deviation',self.semistddv()[0]],
            ['Annualised Semi Standard Deviation',self.semistddv()[1]]])
```

What would the best way of going about this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: the `__str__` method should return a length of text. but you're free to write another method that returns a data frame and use that when you want the output as a dataframe

Comment: Is there anywhere you could suggest that would outline how to do that?